# iOS15 Navigation title Not Showing Properly in Some Devices SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigation, ios15

I'm trying to figure out why the navigation title is not working with some devices, but I'm not able to figure out this issue. Can any one please help me to find out this issue, why the navigation title shows only the first 3 letters and after showing?

I have attached the **Screenshot** also please check.

**iPhone 11 Device**

[image: Screenshot]

**iPhone 11 Simulator**

[image: Screenshot]

**Code:-**

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.init(ColorConstantsName.MainThemeBgColour)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                Text("Testing")
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .navigationTitle(CommonAllString.BlankStr)
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .navigationBarItems(leading:AnyView(leadingButton),trailing:AnyView(self.trailingButton))
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
}

var trailingButton: some View {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: ImageConstantsNameForChatScreen.PersonImg)
            .padding(.trailing)
        Image(ImageConstantsName.DTRShareIconImg)
            .resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can't reproduce with what you have but the `navigationBarItems` and `navigationBarTitleDisplayMode` are deprecated you should change to `.toolbar` in iOS 14 and 15 you might get better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Below Code Working:-**

```
struct PSScreen: View {

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.init("Colour")
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack{
            Text("PSScreen")
        }
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            leadingButton.frame(width: 50, alignment: .leading)
        }
        
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            trailingButton
        }
    }.foregroundColor(Color.white)
}

var leadingButton: some View {
    HStack{
        Text("Profile")
    }
}

var trailingButton: some View {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "Person")
            .padding(.trailing)
        Image("Share")
            .resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20)
       }
    }
}
```